# LCP pageSpeed and a JS slider, how to optimise?

Tags: optimization, owl-carousel, pagespeed

So i have first time in my life a task about optimising a webpage. I got well with the task after reading google docs - web vitals. I optimised from 1-5 score to 70-75. The last thing to do now is optimise LCP - largest content paint.

**Problem** is that after slider initialization (when owl.carousel.min.js and jquery libs are loaded) LCP time marker is moved futher on timeline.

To explain more clearly: if you ever optimised FCP, LCP, FP, you know about Perfomance tab in Google Chrome Dev and a frames that appear there. I have inlined css above the fold for elements that first appear - slider is among them. My styles for slider looks exactly the same as styles from owl.carousel.css before it loads. There are no white space or any kind of blinks on frames.

**However** When owl.carousel.js lib is loaded LCP time marker is moved to that moment, even though, i repeat, LCP doesnt change in frames at all, looks 100% the same. Even thought same looking img on slider appeared long ago, LCP is moved to the moment in time when owl.js is loaded.

I have read that LCP is re-set if src attribute of img changes - but i use the same img all time. May be code inside slider re-sets src and i get LCP re-set, but changing code of slider library is not solution, for sure.

So how do i optimise LCP time if my LCP is a js library slider that depends on jquery? Loading jquery with a slider in head is bad solution - gives even worse results because of render blocking and scripts evaluation.

Comment: i know it is a bit of work but can you set up a fiddle for this (or share the site URL in the comments). At the moment there are several things that could be the cause of this. Do you know how to run a performance trace. If you do set CPU slowdown to 4 times, network speed to "fast 3G" and then hit "record" and reload the page. You can use the profiling to see how things are being rendered etc. there. It could be that the `src` attribute gets reset as you suggest but that is guessing without seeing some code / having something to test against.

Comment: sure, website is keratin-premium.pro. after openning main page you will notice a slider appears at top of the page. there is a small delay of around 1-2 secs in loading browser for better page speed load.

Comment: I know about Perfomance page and i tested site there a lot. It's that place where i found that LCP is being reset after owl.carousel.js is loaded. In frames you can see that LCP is constant , and you can compare styles before owl.carousel.js(and .css) is loaded and after. I added above-the-fold css styles to LCP just same as in library, but however as i said LCP is being re-set somewhy.

Comment: Right, when the owl carousel is loaded the `.owl-stage` element is the largest drawn item. I am guessing this is to do with `transform: translate3d` taking it out of the document flow for a micro second when the style is applied. Because it has to paint all of the images at once it registers this as the largest paint even though visually there is only a minor flash (with CPU slowdown). Not sure how you could sort that with owl slider though. I would perhaps go custom or remove the slider entirely (as sliders have been shown to be useless anyway).

Comment: Thanks for keeping discussion up, Graham, i agree on your point about how it interrupts proccess of LCP tracking, and i also cannot find a proper solution for that. Removing slider is not an option since it's part of my client website design - main element.

Comment: swap it out for an alternative that behaves correctly I think is the solution. Not a fun job if it is integrated into a CMS but if they are spending any money / time on marketing for the company it will pay for itself quite quickly in increased conversions.